# Swagger - TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SecurityScheme' from assembly 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I've upgraded a REST API to .NetCore 3 and it no longer starts up - instead giving me this error.

TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SecurityScheme' from assembly 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger, Version=6.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxx

I've got the latest Swashbuckle packages installed:
[image]

In my Startup class:
ConfigureServices

```
    #region SWAGGER
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1.6", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Data In", Version = "1.6" });

                c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
            });

            services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();

            services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);
            });

#endregion
```

then under Configure:

```
            // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui assets (HTML, JS, CSS etc.)
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "Data In");
        });
```

Project CLI:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <UserSecretsId>3a8b4661-0617-482b-9461-bdbcf7df7ad5</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.Security.Jwt" Version="1.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DAL\DAL.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I'm probably missing something really simple.

FULL Error Message:
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SecurityScheme' from assembly 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger, Version=6.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=62657d7474907593'.
AspNetCore.Security.Jwt.SwaggerExtensions+<>c.b__8_0(SwaggerGenOptions c)
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions.Configure(string name, TOptions options)
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory.Create(string name)
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__0()
System.Lazy.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
System.Lazy.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, bool useDefaultConstructor)
System.Lazy.CreateValue()
System.Lazy.get_Value()
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache.GetOrAdd(string name, Func createOptions)
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager.Get(string name)
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager.get_Value()
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.ConfigureSwaggerGeneratorOptions..ctor(IOptions swaggerGenOptionsAccessor, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnv)
System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(object target, object[] arguments, Signature sig, bool constructor, bool wrapExceptions)
System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitNoCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.SwaggerGenServiceCollectionExtensions+<>c.b__0_1(IServiceProvider s)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type middleware)
lambda_method(Closure , object , HttpContext , IServiceProvider )
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass4_1.b__2(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, ICorsPolicyProvider corsPolicyProvider)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass4_1.b__2(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: You have a version mismatch. Install only `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`, it brings rest of the packages transitively, remove the others. https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#getting-started

Comment: Hi Abdusco - I tried that, I still get the same error message.

I'd installed the other package (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.NewtonSoft) following the guide, since we're using the Newtonsoft.JSON package in the project.

Comment: Can you your post .csproj file?

Comment: Hi Abdusco, I've edited the question to include the .csproj data